# Figuring out if all but one array elements are identical

Tags: java

Does anyone know how I would work out if all elements in an array but one have the same value?

I have been trying to work it out for ages but cannot solve it. For example testing an array that has 5 elements to see if it has 4 identical values.

Thanks

Comment: So java **or** C? They are different languages, so you'd better choose just one.

Comment: Oh, and note that C is **not** C++ either.

Answer (score 4):

Use a map.

```
Map<X, Integer> map = new HashMap<X, Integer>(); // where X is the array type
Integer ct;
for(X item : array){
    ct = map.get(item);
    if(ct == 0) ct = Integer.valueOf(1);
    else ct = Integer.valueOf(ct.intValue()+1);
    map.put(item, ct);
}
// now test if map.values() consists of Integer.valueOf(1) and (optionally)
// another positive integer (thx aioobe)
```

Comment: I believe you're missing an `else`.

Comment: @aioobe correct, thx, also changed my code to only do 1 lookup per item

Comment: To be precise: If the array contains 1 element, then all values except one are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Step by Step:

1. Get the first element.
2. Loop all the array elements and count the number of times they don't
   match that first element.

   - If all of the elements match, you have your answer (all are equal).
   - If only one of the elements do not match, you have your answer (one
     is different).
   - If some of the elements do not match, you have your answer (more than
     one is different).
3. In none of the elements match, get the second element and repeat the
   test.

   - If only one of the elements do not match, again only one is different (the first one).
   - Else, the number of different elements is bigger than one.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would choose is:

iterate over all elements and put them in a Map (HashMap in Java).

the key is the element, and the value is the counter of the appearance.

example: your array: A A A A B

map:

A -> 4
B -> 1

After you have constructed that map it's easy to find out if your array matches that criteria.

1. The map must have exactly 2 elements (map.size()).
2. Exactly one of the elements has the counter 1.

If you assume that adding to a map happens in constant time you'll have an overall complexity of 2n (iterate over array and iterate over map).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this trick :-)

```
public static boolean allButOneSame(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length <= 1)
        return arr.length == 1;

    Arrays.sort(arr);

    return  arr[0] != arr[arr.length-1] &&
           (arr[0] == arr[arr.length-2] ||
            arr[1] == arr[arr.length-1]);
}
```

(Relies on comparable values such as integers though!)

Comment: It's only one part of the requirement, but it's nice and simple (+1)

Comment: Which part of the requirement is missing?... oh, you mean I assumed integers... true!

Comment: Posted a more general solution, taking arbitrary types into account [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940317/figuring-out-if-all-but-one-array-elements-are-identical/6941102#6941102) :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate array, by comparing 1st element and x+1 elements where x is 2,3,4,...array.length()
2. If comparison fails then increment a counter

if ((counter==0) || ((counter> 1) && (counter != array.length-1))) then condition is not met

counter=0 means, all are same elements

counter=array.length-1 means sorted order eg: 4,5,5,5,5,5,5

Complexity ->time: O(n), no extra space other than counter

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
public static <Item> boolean allButOneSame(List<Item> items) {

    // Make sure we have 2 different elements (or 1 element in total)
    if (new HashSet<Item>(items).size() != 2)
        return items.size() == 1;

    // Create a temporary copy
    List<Item> tmp = new ArrayList<Item>(items);

    // Remove all elements equal to the first one.
    tmp.removeAll(Collections.singleton(items.get(0)));

    // Check the number of remaining elements.
    return tmp.size() == 1 || tmp.size() == items.size() - 1;
}
```

It takes a `List` as input. Use `Arrays.asList` if start with an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add all array elements into a `LinkedHashSet` (no duplicates, insertion order is preserved) and look at the set's `.size()`